Snowflake: OBJECT(field TYPE) not supported
I'm trying to create the following table in Snowflake:
CREATE OR ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    a OBJECT(b VARCHAR(100))
);

and I get the following error:
Unsupported data type 'OBJECT(b VARCHAR(100))'.

I expect this to work based on the documentation.
Any idea what is causing this? Or what is the syntax to create an object with a named field?

Hi - if you read the documentation you linked to it tells you which table types support OBJECT datatypes

According to this, only Iceberg tables support structured types.

The direct use of the OBJECT type is not supported in Snowflake. You can use VARIANT instead, which helps you store data in JSON format.
Example:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
  a VARIANT
);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (a) 
VALUES (PARSE_JSON('{"b": "some value"}'));
SELECT a:b FROM TEST_TABLE;


Hi Harun, I'm pretty sure your example also works if you replace VARIANT with OBJECT. As far as I understand, the difference is that VARIANT can be any json value (number, string, array, object) while OBJECT can be, well, an object.
